# Get the resources under a specific div (wget, xmllint, etc)

Tags: xml, curl, xml-parsing, wget, xmllint

I already managed to get a section of the website I wanted. But, without the resources (audio).

```sh
wget -q -O - "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/admirable" | xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class = "pos-header dpos-h"]' - 2>/dev/null > admirable-wget
```

This is the section of the website,

[image]

How can I include it in a path or something? I would like to play it with mpv, latter in the script I'm building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the path to the media file with this XPath expression:

```
string(//amp-audio[@id="ampaudio1"]/source[@type="audio/ogg"]/@src)
```

Full command

```
wget -q -O - "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/admirable" | xmllint --recover --html --xpath 'string(//amp-audio[@id="ampaudio1"]/source[@type="audio/ogg"]/@src)'
```

Result

```
/media/english/uk_pron_ogg/u/uka/ukadj/ukadjus011.ogg
```

Then download it

```
wget -q "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/uk_pron_ogg/u/uka/ukadj/ukadjus011.ogg"
```

Note: check site's [terms of use](https://www.cambridge.org/legal/website-terms-of-use)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I ended up using a mix of python and shell. But, your approach is way more concise.

I read their terms. For now, I'm on the "Only use the Site and its content for personal, non-commercial purposes." category. Thanks for pointing it out. My script is so I can access the pronunciation of words rapidly in the terminal, and so I can better my pronunciation.